# Why does TypeScript define properties on the prototype and not the object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a data object and I have defined a property in TypeScript like:

```
get name() {
    return this._hiddenName;
}
set name(value) {
    ...stuff...
    this._hiddenName = value;
}
```

but when I go the output code I see

```
Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, "name", {
```

so the property exists on the prototype and not the object. That is fine when I want to call it, but when I want to go over the properties of the object with Object.keys() these properties will not be picked up.

Specifically I am passing an object with properties into a FormGroup in Angular and that tries to map the object to the form using Object.keys which finds my backing properties, but not the properties I actually want to expose.

Comment: That's right, `name` is not own property so it's not listed by `Object.keys`. And it's absolutely correct that it's defined on prototype because you told it be there by using class member for name.

Comment: Okay, so my assumption was that properties were designed for encapsulation so you could make something behave just like a basic value on an object. In fact, JavaScript has a "enumerable" which makes a property show up like a normal part of the object (in Object.keys()). TypeScript actually sets "enumerable: true" but then takes the property off the object and puts in on to the prototype which specifically disables both the intent of "enumerable:true" and the idea that a property acts like a normal value to the outside world.

Comment: Enumerable properties on the prototype *are* included when you iterate with `for ... in`.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a class, all the methods and getters/setters will be in the prototype:

```
class MyObject {
  private _hiddenName: string
  get name() {
    return this._hiddenName;
  }
  set name(value) {
      this._hiddenName = value;
  }
}
```

But you could define an object:

```
let obj = {
  _hiddenName: "abc",
  get name() {
    return this._hiddenName;
  },
  set name(value) {
      this._hiddenName = value;
  }
}
```

Here, the getter and the setter are in the object. The compiled code is the same as the TypeScript code.